# Extension of a zero linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

How can I show using Hahn-Banach theorem that, if $E$ is a real vector space, $F$ is a proper vector subspace of $E$, and f is the zero linear functional $f:F\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ $\forall x \in F$, then there is linear functional $g:E\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=0$ $\forall x \in F$ and $g(x)\neq0$ for some $x\in E$.

Would this also be true for a complex vector space?

Comment: The "if" part of your question kind of makes no sense. The zero functional always exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathbb K$ be either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

If your spaces are not normed, then continuity/boundedness is irrelevant and you don't need Hahn-Banach. Just take any $x\in E\setminus F$. Now consider the subspace $F'=F+\mathbb K x$. It is a direct sum, as $F\cap\mathbb K x=0$. Define a linear functional $f:F'\to\mathbb K$ by 
$$
f(z+\lambda x)=\lambda,\ \ \ z\in F,\ \lambda\in\mathbb K.
$$
Now consider a basis $\{e_j\}$ of $F$, so $\{x\}\cup\{e_j\}$ is a basis of $F'$. Extend to a basis $\{e_j\}_j\cup\{x\}\cup\{g_l\}$ of $E$, and define $f(g_l)=0$ for all $l$. Then $f$ is a functional on $E$ such that $f|_F=0$, and $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Why was it necessary to set $f(g_l)=0$ for all $l$?

Comment: Not necessary at all. But one has to choose some number.